# HTML meta charset not working

Tags: html

At the beginning of my page, I have the following code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> 
//other
```

I used the `meta` because I have to put in my website some Japanese characters. Here you can see an example:

```
<tr>
<td><label class="blacktd" onmouseover="apriimg('imgbox', '4');"> Shy Guy Bazaar </label></td>
<td><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpmkZIcD7fc">2'03"007</a></td>
<td>そうめん</td> //look at here
<td><img src="http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/flags/jp.gif" /></td>
<td>2013/06/30</td>
</tr>
```

I googled this and I saw that I simply need to put that  tag with the `charset` attribute. By the way my webpage shows `%u305D%u3046%u3081%u3093` instead of "そうめん". Do you know why?

Comment: If your page “shows `%u305D%u3046%u3081%u3093` instead of "そうめん"”, then there’s a lot you haven’t told us. Posting a real URL might be a quick route to showing what the problem really is.

Comment: "then there’s a lot you haven’t told us" but @Quentin answered immediatly in a correct way that helped me a lot. I don't think he is a genius, he just used this knowleage for an USEFUL answer.

Comment: If you think Quentin’s answer solved your problem, please accept it. The fact still is that no normal charset confusion produces `%u305D%u3046%u3081%u3093`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because either:

- You have an HTTP header which specifies a different character encoding (HTTP headers take priority over meta elements) *or*
- You haven't saved the document using UTF-8 (you are just telling the browser that you are)

Comment: and so? what could I do?

Comment: Check your HTTP headers (e.g. with Chrome Developer Tools net tab) and, if they are right, configure whatever software you use to create the HTML file with to use UTF-8.

Comment: so it is my browser's "fault"?

Comment: It isn't even slightly the fault of the browser.

Answer (score 5):

Is your doctype HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

if not you have to use this for all other doctypes

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all answerers, but I have had troubles solving it, as I saved the file in two editors (Leafpad and vim) as UTF-8, still getting weird characters in browser. The culprit was, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310274/how-can-i-use-vim-to-convert-my-file-to-utf8), the byte order mark, which seems not to be set by default in both the editors but has to be set explicitly in vim:

```
:set bomb
```

This solved the problem for me finally.

Comment: exactly, solved it for me, thanks!!