# Console2 - diacritical characters in Git vim

Tags: git, vim, console2

For some time I use Console2 and it's perfect for me except one annoying thing. I've created new Git tab with shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i. This thing happens when I commit changes in vim. When I'm typing diacritical characters I get unexpected output eg ^ instead of ł. After typing commit message and close it by typing :wq output back to normal. All diacritical characters are preserved. This is revealed only while I'm typing in vim. In addition, when I'm using Git Bash, everything is fine. It is possible to fix this.

Comment: Does the same thing happens in normal Windows console, started from Win+R? If so - it is not a Console bug. Also, you may try another emulator - ConEmu.

Comment: No, in Windows cmd is everything fine. I used ConEmu but I prefer Console2.

Comment: Strange... why you prefer it, interesting? Anyway, you may try [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) fork. Seems like it's not abandoned like original.

Comment: I prefer it because it works with Ansicon and there is no problem with eg JBoss colorizing.

Comment: ConEmu supports ANSI internally, and I believe there is no problems with colorizing. So, it is not an argument, yeah?

Comment: So how to explain no colors when I'm working with JBoss?

Comment: Old version or disabled ANSI in settings. "Inject ConEmuHk" and "ANSI X3.64" must be on. Also, "no colors" is ambiguous. Screenshot?

Comment: I have the newest version, both features are enabled. In Jboss output is only white. When I'm running it in cmd or Console2 warns are yellow, errors are red, debug logs are green. For now JBoss is the only case where problem appears. Git shell or my own bat scripts are colorized well.

Comment: Very strange. Conemu does not block colorizing. Can you create an issue on the project site with description "How to reproduce"?

Comment: JBoss hasn't color in cmd by default until we use ansicon. I heard that JBoss in version 7 has built in colorizing but cmd is blocking it.

Comment: Comments are wrong place to discussion. I believe, this is JBoss configuration issue. And "cmd" can't block anything from colorizing by design, at all. It is **only** the program decision to use colors or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40872/discussion-between-kemot90-and-maximus)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the values of some enconding options of vim, like ['encoding'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-37.3) and ['termencodings'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-37.8).

Additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16507826/717124) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8121753/717124).

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried solve problem by adding encoding setting in vimrc file. It didn't work for me.